# JMX: Wrapped MXBean does not send Notifications

Tags: notifications, jmx

According to the JMX API I can use classes like [StandardMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/StandardMBean.html) and [StandardEmitterMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/StandardEmitterMBean.html) to use customization hooks. SO instead of registering the MXBean itself directly I can wrap it in one of these classes.
This is working fine, but as soon as I try to use the JMX Notification framework no Notification will be fired when using this wrapped class instead of the MXBean directly.
Some example code:

The MXBean interface

```java
public interface MyMXBean {
    public void hello();
}
```

The implementation

```java
public class MyMXBeanImpl extends NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements MyMXBean {

    @Override    
    public void hello() {
        Notification n = //...creating new Notification
        sendNotification(n);
    }
}
```

The Registation:

```java
public class Registration() {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();  
        ObjectName oname = 
            new ObjectName("example:type=myexample,name=MyExamleMXBean");
        // does not fire any notifications      
        mbs.registerMBean(
            new StandardEmitterMBean(new MyMXBeanImpl(), MyMXBean.class, true), oname);

        // would fire the notification
        // mbs.register(new MyMXBeanImpl(), oname);
    }
}
```

When I connect JConsole to my bean, subscribe to the Notification mechanism and execute the hello() Method nothing happens. Only when registering the MXBean directly everything works fine. 
It's also not working when adding custom NotificationListeners to my MXBean.
I've already tried to somehow catch this Notification event in the wrapping class and forward it somehow but this didn't work either.
Do you have any idea what I am missing here? Or is it just not working when using one of the wrapping classes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Briefly ( on mobile u see ), you need to extend your class to provide notification-info metadata for your notification types.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nicholas. That's what I've found out, too. Seems that JMX is applying the notification to the wrapping class and does not forward it to the wrapped one.